# MVC3 model - how to make it so editorfor is a dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am making a MVC4 webapp for peers at 2 colleges to use, and later on I will expand to other schools. In my model I currently have

```
       public string school { get; set; }
```

I would like it so when I do

```
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.school)
```

It would be a drop down of "school 1" and "School 2".

How can I go about doing this cleanly? If I can, I would like to be able to make the change in the model and not have to do anything in the view besides call @Html.EditorFor. If the only way to accomplish this is do something in the view, that is OK as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Html.EditorFor` you can use `Html.DropDownListFor`

```
@{
   var items = new SelectList(new[]
                   {
                       new SelectListItem {Text = "School1", Value = "School1"},
                       new SelectListItem {Text = "School2", Value = "School2"},
                   }, "Text", "Value");
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.school, @items)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just to make sure I understand, I should put all of this in the view, yes?

Comment: Yes, this should be put in your view. It uses the Razor syntax. Probably you want to move the list of possible items to your controller and put them in your viewmodel. But for quick demo purposes this works fine :)

Comment: Try changing the Text and Value properties of the SelectListItem

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use above code or you can go with this code in your page.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                       new SelectListItem{ Text="New", Value = "New" },
                       new SelectListItem{ Text="InProcess", Value = "InProcess" },
                       new SelectListItem{ Text="Completed", Value = "Completed" },
                       new SelectListItem{ Text="Rejected",Value="Rejected"},

                    }, "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control select2_demo_4" })
```

This will surely help you out and you can get value in your model when you select any of it.